# Como convertir un proyecto backend de nestjs v10 a 9v?

Tags: nodejs, migration, packages, nestjs, control-de-versiones

Tengo un proyecto de Nestjs con la version 10.1.11 en la cual ya tengo un backend algo avanzado pero al subirlo a mi hosting solo acepta la version de node v14.21.2 por lo cual la version de nestjs que tengo no es soportada asi que he pensado en realizar el siguiente proceso

1.- Usar nvm y descargar la version de node que soporta mi hosting (v14.21.2)
2.- Instalar @nestjs/cli version 9 que es soportada por esa version
3.- Crear un nuevo proyecto de nestjs con esa version
4.- Ir agregando modulos archivos y paqueterías de manera individual al nuevo proyecto

Cual es la forma correcta de hacer el proceso de manera mas sencilla sin la necesidad de crear un nuevo proyecto, es mi primera vez haciendo una migración de una version a otra.

Comment: Un _downgrade_ o _upgrade_ siempre es algo que tomará tiempo y no hay atajos o caminos fáciles. Por otro lado, tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones, por lo cual podría terminar cerrada. Te invito a repasar [ask] y lo que dice el [help/on-topic] sobre el tipo de preguntas que se aceptan en [es.so].

Comment: Si entiendo tu punto pero yo lo que quiero saber es si es correcto el proceso que estoy haciendo o de que forma es la correcta para hacerlo?